# ASP.NET MVC ViewBag's relation to client-side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How does the ViewBag relate to client-side validation?

Consider the following example. I have two action-methods both named Test one takes get-requests and the other post-requests.

The get-action returns a view, where user can edit the value of a select. The value of this select is a nullable int. If a value for this select is found from session then it is set as selected.

The post-action adds the submitted value to session and redirects the user back to the get-action.

This code works the following way: The first time after a non-null value is submitted, client-side validation is applied, but only if i add a value to the ViewBag that has the same name as the select has. So my question is why? I would really like to understand why this works the way it does. From what i have read the ViewBag(ViewDataDictionary) is only used for passing data to the view and i have never read that it effects validation.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    int? id = (int?)Session["id"];
    List<SelectListItem> options = new List<SelectListItem>();
    options.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = 1 == id, Text = "Option 1", Value = "1" });
    options.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = 2 == id, Text = "Option 2", Value = "2" });
    options.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = 3 == id, Text = "Option 3", Value = "3" });
    ViewBag.Options = options;
    ViewBag.id = id; //This adds client side validation
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(int? id)
{
    Session["id"] = id;
    return RedirectToAction("Test");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("id", "Select")
    @Html.DropDownList("id", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Options, "Empty")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never give the same name to the ViewBag variable and your properties from your model. All these values in the end reside in FormCollection and when two of them have the same name/key they override each other and you get some really funky behavior. I'm not sure what the issue is precisely with your scenario (usually people have a ViewModel of some sort) but consider the following scenario:

```
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

if this is your model and in your controller action you do something like:

```
public ActionResult EditProduct(int id)
{
   var model = ProductDomainLogic.GetProduct(id);
   ViewBag.ProductName = "Whatever";
   return View(model);
}
```

you just gave yourself a serious headache because there are 2 elements that have the same name and they will overwrite each other in the FormCollection. So to summarize always name your ViewBag variables with some name that has NOT been used in the model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that ViewBag is connected to FormCollection.